# post in one specfic array while loop

Tags: php, web

I want to post value in one row while doing loop in specific array by id, but when click on bottom then will post it in "response" row in all arrays of table!!

```
<?php

require_once('config.php');

$con->set_charset('utf8');

$query = "select * from contact order by id";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$query);

while($name = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

    echo '<table width="200" border="1" align="right">';

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <div align='center'> <b> $name[id] </b> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <div align='center'> <b> The number </b> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <div align='center'> <b> $name[ticketnumber] </b> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <div align='center'> <b> ticket number </b> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <b> $name[name] </b> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <b> name </b> </div> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> $name[phone] </b>  </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <b> phone </b>  </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'>  <b> $name[email] </b>  </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> email </b>  </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> $name[subject] </b> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> subject </b>  </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> $name[response] </b> </td>";
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> response </b>  </td>";
    echo "</tr>";
    echo "<tr>";
    echo ' <td align="center"> <form method="POST" action="showcontact.php">
<input type="text" name="response" height="50pt"/> <br/>
<input type="submit" value="send" name="send"> </form> </td>';
    echo "<td align='center'> <b> answer </b> </td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    if(isset($_POST['response'])) {

        $response = $_POST['response'];

        $sql = ("UPDATE contact SET response = '$response' WHERE id= $name[id]");

        $rst = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

        if($rst){

            echo "<td align='center'> <b> sent </b>  </td>" ;
            echo " <td align='center'>  </td>";
        } else {
            echo "<td align='center'> <b> did not send </b>  </td>";
            echo " <td align='center'>  </td>";

            echo "</table>";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Could you explain some more and create a JSFiddle?

Comment: This php code upper will post in all table arrays, I want to post in one specific array as I said like I do update for array not posting new array.

Answer (score 0):

Having everything in a loop makes it hard to read your code.

You need a contact id to attach a response to.

Here's a brief overview of how I'd do it:

```
loop through contacts
    row begins
        display contact info
        display response form
    row ends
end loop

response form:
    give it a post method
    add a hidden contact id field <-- 
    response input (text)
    submit button

Form processing logic:
    if this is a post request, and we have an id and response:
        do your SQL update
```

I'd place the form processing out the loop at the top of your script, or on another page.

Comment: So do I have put codes outside of loop and make the  loop end before post?